# Joining 3 tables with n:m relationship, want to see nonmatching rows

Tags: mysql, join

For this problem, consider the following 3 tables:

```
Event
id (pk)
title

Event_Category
event_id (pk, fk)
category_id (pk, fk)

Category
id (pk)
description
```

Pretty trivial I guess... :) Each event can fall into zero or more categories, in total there are 4 categories.
In my application, I want to view and edit the categories for a specific event. Graphically, the event will be shown together with ALL categories and a checkbox indicating whether the event falls into the category. Changing and saving the choice will result in modifocation of the intermediate table Event_Category.
But first: how to select this for a specific event? The query I need will in fact always return 4 rows, the number of categories present.

Following returns only the entries for the categories the event with id=11 falls into. Experimenting with outer joins did not give more rows in the result.

```
SELECT e.id, c.omschrijving 
FROM Event e
  INNER JOIN Event_Categorie ec ON e.id = ec.event_id
  INNER JOIN Categorie c ON c.id = ec.categorie_id
WHERE e.id = 11
```

Or should I start with the Category table in the query? Hope for some hints :)
TIA, Klaas

**UPDATE:**
Yes I did but still have not found the answer. But I have simplified the issue by omitting the Event table from the query because this table is only used to view the Event descriptions.

```
SELECT * from Categorie c LEFT JOIN Event_Categorie ec ON c.id = ec.categorie_id WHERE ec.event_id = 11;
```

The simplified 2-table query only uses the lookup table and the link table but still returns only 2 rows instead of the total of 4 rows in the Categorie table.
My guess would be that the WHERE clause is applied after the joining, so the rows not joined to the link table are excluded. In my application I solved the issues by using a subquery but I still would like to know what is the best solution.

Comment: this kind of question has been asked and answered here many times before. Did you try searching StackOverflow before you posted this?

Comment: Yes I did but still have not found the answer. But I have simplified the issue.

Comment: see update under my original question

Answer (score 0):

What you want is the list of all categories, plus information about whether that category is in the list of categories of your event.

So, you can do:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    Category 
    LEFT JOIN Event_Category ON category_id = id 
WHERE 
    event_id = 11
```

and event_id column will be NULL on the categories that are not part of your event.

You can also create a column (named has_category below) that you will use to see if the event has this category instead of comparing with NULL:

```
SELECT 
    *,
    event_id IS NOT NULL AS has_category
FROM 
    Category 
    LEFT JOIN Event_Category ON category_id = id 
WHERE 
    event_id = 11
```

EDIT: This seems exactly what you say you are doing on your edit. I tested it and it seems correct. Are you sure you are running this query, and that rows with NULL are not somehow ignored?

Comment: See above, excuses for the bad layout, still figuring out how it works :)

Comment: so... both of your queries only return 2 rows, only the one with the subselect works as required.

Comment: what platform do you use? this is not what I see on a common MySQL setup, running the queries on the terminal.

Comment: I use Ubuntu Linux with Apache, indeed I run the queries from the console for testing, I also use PHPMyAdmin as there are few good graphical MySQL clients for Linux.

Answer (score 0):

The query

```
SELECT * FROM Categorie;
```

returns 4 rows:

```
+----+--------------+-------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+
| id | omschrijving | afbeelding                          | afbeelding_klein                     |
+----+--------------+-------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+
|  1 | Creatief     | images/categorieen/creatief420k.jpg | images/categorieen/creatief190k.jpg  |
|  2 | Sportief     | images/categorieen/sportief420k.jpg | images/categorieen/sportief190kr.jpg |
|  4 | Culinair     | images/categorieen/culinair420k.jpg | images/categorieen/culinair190k.jpg  |
|  5 | Spirit       | images/categorieen/spirit420k.jpg   | images/categorieen/spirit190k.jpg    |
+----+--------------+-------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

BUT:
The query

```
SELECT * 
FROM Categorie 
LEFT JOIN Event_Categorie ON categorie_id = id 
WHERE event_id = 11;
```

returns 2 rows:

```
+----+--------------+-------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+----------+--------------+
| id | omschrijving | afbeelding                          | afbeelding_klein                    | event_id | categorie_id |
+----+--------------+-------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+----------+--------------+
|  1 | Creatief     | images/categorieen/creatief420k.jpg | images/categorieen/creatief190k.jpg |       11 |            1 |
|  4 | Culinair     | images/categorieen/culinair420k.jpg | images/categorieen/culinair190k.jpg |       11 |            4 |
+----+--------------+-------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+----------+--------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

So I still need the subquery... and the LEFT JOIN is not effective in showing all rows of the CAtegorie table, regardless whether there is a match with the link table.

This query, however, does what I want it to do:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Categorie c 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM Event_Categorie ec WHERE ec.event_id = 11 ) AS subselect ON  subselect.categorie_id = c.id;
```

Result:

```
+----+--------------+-------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+----------+--------------+
| id | omschrijving | afbeelding                          | afbeelding_klein                     | event_id | categorie_id |
+----+--------------+-------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+----------+--------------+
|  1 | Creatief     | images/categorieen/creatief420k.jpg | images/categorieen/creatief190k.jpg  |       11 |            1 |
|  2 | Sportief     | images/categorieen/sportief420k.jpg | images/categorieen/sportief190kr.jpg |     NULL |         NULL |
|  4 | Culinair     | images/categorieen/culinair420k.jpg | images/categorieen/culinair190k.jpg  |       11 |            4 |
|  5 | Spirit       | images/categorieen/spirit420k.jpg   | images/categorieen/spirit190k.jpg    |     NULL |         NULL |
+----+--------------+-------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+----------+--------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: And I still do not get why the first query only returns 2 rows despite use of the LEFT JOIN... :(

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you have filtered the results by the eventid. As you can see in your results, two of the categories (Sportief and Spirit) do not have events. So the correct SQL statement (using SQL Server syntax; some translation may be required) is:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Categorie 
LEFT JOIN Event_Categorie ON categorie_id = id 
WHERE (event_id IS NULL) OR (event_id = 11);
```

Comment: I tested this one and it still returns only 2 rows... not so strange because the missing rows are the one who have no match with the Event_Category table, so checking the event)_id for zero does not do the trick.
Still the only working query is the one with the subselect.

Comment: Moreover, the event_id field of the link table is never NULL because it is part of the primary key! Indeed, when omitting the WHERE clause compeltely, the result contains 44 rows but none of them with event_id = null. So this is clearly not the cause.

Comment: When you do a left join, if there are no items in the Event_Categorie table for a given Categorie, then the event_id must be null. This is the point of the LEFT JOIN; give all records in the first table and, if there are any records in the second table that match the join condition, show them as well, otherwise show nulls for the second table. You can see this exact behavior in your last result table where every other row has a null event_id.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the right query, no subselect is necessary. But the WHERE clause works after the joining and therefore is no part of the join anymore. THe solution is extending the ON clause with an extra condition. Now all 4 rows are returned with NULL for the non-matching Categories!

```
SELECT * 
FROM Categorie  
LEFT JOIN Event_Categorie ON categorie_id = id AND event_id = 11;
```

So the bottom line is that putting an extra condition in the ON clause has different effect than filtering out rows by the same condition in the WHERE clause!